# Sigma computation

Tags: measure-theory

if this is true, I would like to see some steps.

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 - (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} X_j)^2$

Comment: What are the $X_i $?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_jX_j$. Then,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_i(X_i-\bar{X})^2&=\frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_iX_i^2-2\Big(\sum_iX_i\Big)\bar{X}+n\bar{X}^2\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_iX_i^2-2(n\bar{X})\bar{X}+n\bar{X}^2\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_iX_i^2-n\bar{X}^2\right]
\end{aligned}
which is your LHS.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to revert to arithmetic, and want to express it in terms of measures and expected values of random variables, you can do this as follows:

Assuming that $\{X_i\}_{i=1..n}$ is just a fixed list of some real numbers, you can define a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mu := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$, where $\delta_{x}$ are the measures that assign weight $1$ to the element $x$. Let $X$ be the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$. It is obviously measurable, thus it can be treated as a $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$. Your equality now says:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2] \,, $$
which is true simply by linearity of $\mathbb{E}$:
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2 - 2\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot X + \mathbb{E}[X]^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - 2\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 =  \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 $$